# How to get client secret via Keycloak API?

Tags: python, api, keycloak

How to get client secret via Keycloak API?

In documentation I see:

`GET /admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{id}/client-secret`

My code is the following:

```
data = {
    "grant_type" : 'password',
    "client_id" : 'myclientid',
    "username" : 'myusername',
    "password" : 'mypassword'
}
response = requests.get("https://mylink.com/auth/admin/realms/{myrealm}/clients/{myclientid}/client-secret", data=data, headers= {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

I always get 401 error.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your authentication it's not working.

1. You need a token. You can generate using OpenID (see [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/oidc/oidc-generic.html)).
2. With the token (by header Authorization), you can do request to API.

Example:

Get the token

```
data = {"username": "username", "password": "password",
        "client_id": "client_id", "client_secret": "client_secret", 
        "grant_type": "password"}

token = request.post("https://{server-url}/"realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token", data=data)
```

Request to API

```
response = requests.get("https://mylink.com/auth/admin/realms/{myrealm}/clients/{myclientid}/client-secret", data=data, headers= {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token.get('access_token'), "Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Marcos. The only thing is that to obtain token you need to know client_secret. The purpose of my request is to get client_secret, means I don't know it.

Comment: You don't need the "client_secret" to access "admin-cli".

In this case, your data is {"username": "username", "password": "secret",  "client_id": "admin-cli", "grant_type": "password"}.

But your user must have access to "admin-cli"

Answer (score 15):

**You can't get `client_secret` for public clients. Your client should have 'access_type` = 'confidential'**

1. Go to `CLIENTS` section of your realm admin panel *(`<protocol>://<host>:<port>/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/<your realm>/clients/<your client code>`)*
2. Change Access Type to `confidential` [image: confidential]
3. Press 'SAVE'
4. Go to the "Credentials" tab
5. Make sure that 'Client Authenticator' = 'Client Id and Secret'
6. Voila! Here's your client secret:

[image: secret]

**UPD** P.S. `client_secret` retrieving using API is **[possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540219/8397480) through another client** *(which should have role for client info view)*

Comment: What is written in the PS is not true. You can get the client secret for login clients that have access type confidential via API call. See other answers.

Answer (score 8):

{id} in the URL is not clientId, it is different from clientId. 
it is keycloak unique id ( which is `uuid` ) some thing like `628e4b46-3d79-454f-9b1c-e07e86ee7615`

> GET /admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{id}/client-secret

You can get id using this api , where it returns list of ClientRepresentation, which has both **Id** and **clientId**, use **Id**

> GET /{realm}/clients

`

Comment: still 401 error. I think problem is in authorization. I`m doing something wrong.

Comment: Your myusername user should have realm-management  Client Role, but if user does not have the role then it should show up has 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reponse by @ravthiru you can retrieve the client-secret from the 'Instalation' tab on the admin console, select a format like JSON and the client-secret would be in `credentials.secret`