# Keycloak.json configuration file import

Tags: go, kubernetes, keycloak

I have configured my goclient with keycloak.I am reading the keycloak server details from keycloak.json file which is present inside my Go client.
My whole setup is in Kubernetes cluster.Everytime when new keycloak server comes up how should I pass keycloak.json file to the Go client so that it can read the details from json file?
Is there a way I can get the keycloak.json file with all the client configuration details without having to login to keycloak and download it ?

```
  "realm": "SolutionAdmin",
  "auth-server-url": "localhost:8081/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "admin",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "6ee0f523-c392-4406-bb14-ba315125c6ea"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Comment: want client configuration changes each time ? Do you mean keycloak url.

Comment: My Go Client gets the Keycloak info from the keycloak.json file..
So everytime my solution will generate a new keycloak server..So if there was a way I can feed this keycloak.json file to my Go Client dynamically

Comment: you can keep you domain name same and access it using that name instead of ip

Comment: Lets suppose even if i keep the domain name same,I still will have to get the client secret.In my current scenario there will be different load balancer IP for Keycloak.

Comment: You can use api to get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538100/how-to-get-client-secret-via-keycloak-api

Comment: You can also set secret while creating client.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a pre-configured embedded keycloak server, you'll need to extend `KeycloakApplication` and have it configured to trigger in lieu of the base class. in this example, `KeycloakProperties` is just a representation of all the keycloak properties we used in `application.properties`. but you can get the gist of it. fair warning: i did not write this, but am figuring out how a coworker did for another project.

```
public class EmbeddedKeycloakApplication extends KeycloakApplication {

  public final KeycloakProperties keycloakProperties;

  public EmbeddedKeycloakApplication() {

    super();

    keycloakProperties = SpringContextAdapter.getBean(KeycloakProperties.class);
    System.getProperties().putAll(keycloakProperties.getRealmProperties());

    createMasterRealmAdminUser();

    createRealm();
  }

  private void createMasterRealmAdminUser() {

    log.debug("Creating administrative user.");

    String username = keycloakProperties.getServer(KeycloakProperties.ADMIN_USER_USERNAME);
    String password = keycloakProperties.getServer(KeycloakProperties.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD);
    String email = keycloakProperties.getServer(KeycloakProperties.ADMIN_USER_EMAIL);

    KeycloakSession session = getSessionFactory().create();
    ApplianceBootstrap applianceBootstrap = new ApplianceBootstrap(session);

    try {
      session.getTransactionManager().begin();

      if (!applianceBootstrap.isNoMasterUser()) {
        log.debug("Administrative user already exists. No work to do.");
        return;
      }

      applianceBootstrap.createMasterRealmUser(username, password);
      RealmModel adminRealm = session.realms().getRealm(Config.getAdminRealm());
      UserModel adminUser = session.users().getUserByUsername(username, adminRealm);
      adminUser.setEmail(email);
      adminUser.setEmailVerified(true);
      session.getTransactionManager().commit();
      log.info("Created administrative user {}", username);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error("Couldn't create keycloak master admin user: {}", ex.getMessage());
      session.getTransactionManager().rollback();
    }

    session.close();
  }

  private void createRealm() {

    String realmImportFilename = keycloakProperties.getRealmImportFile();
    KeycloakSession session = getSessionFactory().create();
    String realmId = keycloakProperties.getRealm(KeycloakProperties.REALM_ID);

    try {
      session.getTransactionManager().begin();

      RealmManager manager = new RealmManager(session);

      if (manager.getRealm(realmId) != null) {
        log.debug("{} realm already exists. No work to do.", realmId);
        return;
      }

      Resource realmImportFile = new ClassPathResource(realmImportFilename);

      RealmRepresentation rep =
          JsonSerialization.readValue(
              realmImportFile.getInputStream(), RealmRepresentation.class, true);
      manager.importRealm(rep);
      log.info("Imported Realm json file {}", realmImportFilename);
      session.getTransactionManager().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Failed to import Realm json file {}: {}", realmImportFilename, e.getMessage(), e);
      session.getTransactionManager().rollback();
    }

    session.close();
  }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedKeycloakConfig {

  @Bean
  ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet30Dispatcher> keycloakJaxRsApplication(
      KeycloakProperties keycloakProperties, DataSource dataSource) throws NamingException {

    mockJndiEnvironment(dataSource);

    var contextPath = keycloakProperties.getServer(KeycloakProperties.SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH);

    ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet30Dispatcher> servlet =
        new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new HttpServlet30Dispatcher());
    servlet.addInitParameter(
        "javax.ws.rs.Application", EmbeddedKeycloakApplication.class.getName());
    servlet.addInitParameter(
        ResteasyContextParameters.RESTEASY_SERVLET_MAPPING_PREFIX, contextPath);
    servlet.addInitParameter(ResteasyContextParameters.RESTEASY_USE_CONTAINER_FORM_PARAMS, "true");
    servlet.addInitParameter(ResteasyContextParameters.RESTEASY_DISABLE_HTML_SANITIZER, "true");
    servlet.addUrlMappings(contextPath + "/*");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);

    return servlet;
  }

  @Bean
  FilterRegistrationBean<EmbeddedKeycloakRequestFilter> keycloakSessionManagement(
      KeycloakProperties keycloakProperties) {

    FilterRegistrationBean<EmbeddedKeycloakRequestFilter> filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    filter.setName("Keycloak Session Management");
    filter.setFilter(new EmbeddedKeycloakRequestFilter());
    filter.addUrlPatterns(
        keycloakProperties.getServer(KeycloakProperties.SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH) + "/*");

    return filter;
  }

  private void mockJndiEnvironment(DataSource dataSource) throws NamingException {
    NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder(
        env ->
            environment ->
                new InitialContext() {

                  @Override
                  public Object lookup(Name name) {
                    return lookup(name.toString());
                  }

                  @Override
                  public Object lookup(String name) {

                    if ("spring/datasource".equals(name)) {
                      return dataSource;
                    }

                    return null;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public NameParser getNameParser(String name) {
                    return CompositeName::new;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void close() {
                    // NOOP
                  }
                });
  }
}
```