# How to get client secret from Keycloak using curl?

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have setup Keycloak with a Client, that has Access Type confidential and generated a client secret. Now I need to get the client secret via commandline. How can i accomplish that?

Keycloak is running inside a docker container. I've tried to adapt a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538100/how-to-get-client-secret-via-keycloak-api), which targets using python, but I even fail getting a token first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need get Access Token using below curl command for realm `myrealm`

```
curl http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=password&username=testuser&password=test123&client_id=admin-cli'
```

hold `access_token` from above output.

Get the Clients and their ids using

```
curl   http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/clients -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H  'Authorization: Bearer <<ACCESS_TOKEN>>'
```

Get `id` from the output, will some thing like this `"id":"e65ba232-08ff-4f9b-84a6-bd6147340dfd"`

Then get the client secret using below command

```
curl  http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myclient/clients/e65ba232-08ff-4f9b-84a6-bd6147340dfd/client-secret -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H  'Authorization: Bearer <<ACCESS_TOKEN>>'
```

output will be something like this

```
{"type":"secret","value":"9a16ceb5-1f26-4812-ae4d-9e8336efef91"}
```

Comment: Admin token needs be fetched by following command: /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=<password>'

Comment: For more recent versions of Keycloak you must leave out the 'auth' part from all the URLs.